# jquery if text input does *not* equal blank

Tags: jquery

I am trying to work out how to do something if a certain text box is *not* empty (i.e. contain something, could be anything)

This is my code (that doesnt seem to work)

```
if ( !($('#edit-sPostalCode').attr('val','')) ) {
    stuff here
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: There is no HTML element which has a `val` attribute. I think you mean the jQuery method `.val()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if ( $('#edit-sPostalCode').val() != '' ) {
    stuff here
}
```

`$('#edit-sPostalCode').attr('val','')` will actually create an attribute of the input box with a value of `''` and will then return a jQuery object.

Saying `!($('#edit-sPostalCode').attr('val',''))` will then negate that jQuery object. As an instance of an object is [*truthy*](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) in JS the result of this expression will always be `false`.

Comment: It would not set the value, it will add a new attribute with name `val`. But apart from that, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the `.val` method?

```
if ( $('#edit-sPostalCode').val() !== '' ) {
```

Although you ought to `$.trim` the value if you consider whitespace as being equivalent to nothing at all:

```
if ( $.trim( $('#edit-sPostalCode').val() ) !== '' ) {
```

Comment: is !== a javascript operator? I know === is

Comment: Just googled it there - is this the best for this comparison?

Comment: @NicholasMurray It might not matter, but it's better to be safe. For instance, in JavaScript, `false=='0'` is true. `false==''` is also true, although `''=='0'` is false.

Comment: @FelixKling - cool I've changed my answer to use === instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !($('#edit-sPostalCode').val() === '') ) {
    stuff here
}
```