# Animation on form field jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This template i am recreating to learn webdev has an animation which is enabled when a single/multiple character is typed on the form fields.The placeholder fades up in green when any character is typed and fades down when there are no characters in the form field.

here is the template :

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/#

How to implement this animation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has a label tag, and on the CSS it has opacity:0, that means it's invisible, then you need to write with javascript if the input is not empty, if not change the opacity to 1

Comment: If input isn't empty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095822/jquery-if-text-input-does-not-equal-blank

Comment: You are trying to learn webdev. It might be best to figure this one out yourself? You will learn a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking on the input, if the input has more than 1 character show the hidden label.

In other words:
When Keyup, if input length > 0 then opacity will be 1.


Code:

```
$(function(){

$('input').keyup(function(){
    if ( $(this).val().length > 0 ) {
      $(this).prev('label').css('opacity','1');
  }        

    if ( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
       $(this).prev('label').css('opacity','0');
     }
}); 


});
```

In this example the label and the input has to be siblings, It's just an example.

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n2v26cxg/

Comment: Thank you :) It worked fine!

Comment: You're welcome, Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

That's a really cool effect!

This is being achieved with some simple [CSS3 transitions](http://alistapart.com/article/understanding-css3-transitions). You can see the classes being added to the wrappers around the input fields if you open your DOM explorer. The class is `.floating-label-form-group-with-value` and it has a corresponding rule that makes the `<label>` field have an opacity, where normally it is invisible (opacity of 0).

If you are doing this to learn, I will not spoil all the fun by giving you the EXACT code, but here are the basics:

1) The form input fields have a label that is positioned `top:2em` and has `opacity:0` when the page loads

2) There is some kind of javascript that detects when the input changes and applies a class to the parent container, similar to this (I am using jQuery):

`$('#contactForm input').change(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass('has-value');
}`

3)There is a style rule for the added class ( `div.has-value` in this example ) that changes both the `opacity` and the `top` position of the `label` element

4) A `transition` style rule with easing is added to the rule with the added class, that way the `label` will smoothly transition after the class gets added. So, the rules are something like this:

```
#contactForm div label{
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   top:2em;
   opacity:0;
}
#contactForm div.has-value label{
   top:0;
   opacity:1;
   transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
}
```

That's the basics of it. Note, I did not include the vendor prefixes for CSS3 transitions in my example, but you will see if you inspect your original link's code that they covered all the bases with `-ms-transition` and `-moz-transition`.

Keep learning and good luck on your journey!

Comment: Thank you! @CreMedian :)

Answer (score 1):

The example you have posted is checking for a value in the input and then changing a class on the input & label container.

If you watch the code when you type in the input field its container div gets the following class `floating-label-form-group-with-value` added to it. This changes the CSS on the `label` element like so:

```
.floating-label-form-group label {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
  transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
  ...
}

.floating-label-form-group-with-value label {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

As you can see in the code above a css `transition` has been used, this animates the fade in and slide up of the label. Then the change of `top` and `opacity` values define where it moves to and how much it fades in.

The JavaScript for this seems to be controlled by a third party tool called `jqBootstrapValidation` which is a part of the Twitter Bootstrap framework. You can use this for your form or use something like this:

```
$('input').on('change keydown keyup',function (){
   if(!$(this).val() == "") {
     $(this).parent().addClass('floating-label-form-group-with-value');
   }
   else {
     $(this).parent().removeClass('floating-label-form-group-with-value');
   }
});
```

I hope that makes some kind of sense.

Here is a link to a working code example:
    https://jsfiddle.net/31borLqh/

One thing to remember is that what I have provided here only does an animation and does not actually validate the form field, the user could currently submit anything they wanted into this field and it would validate as correct.

Another thing to think about is the UX of this form, the example uses placeholders so you know what to type in the form. When you look at my example, without the placeholder the user has no idea what to type.

Comment: Thank you! :) @lukehillonline